# Why is element height different in Safari than it is in Chrome, Firefox?

Tags: css, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I'm trying to create a "collapsible text" react component that allows a user-determined number of lines to be displayed. I'm using the `line-clamp` CSS property to do this, for the most part. On the JavaScript side of things, I want to selectively render a button that toggles the effect based on whether the content to be shown is greater in height than the number of lines to be shown multiplied by their line height. This is working fairly well in Firefox and Chrome. I can get the line height of the element after it's rendered, and I can multiply that by the number of lines that the user wants shown to approximate the height of the content. I can use that to set a `min-height` CSS property, and I can compare that value against the scroll height of the content. The problem is, I'm getting the same value for the scroll height of the content in Firefox and Chrome, but NOT in Safari.

```
const CollapsibleText = ({
  text,
  linesToShow,
  markdown = false,
  containerStyles,
  textStyles,
  buttonStyles,
  handleScroll,
}) => {
  const [isActive, setIsActive] = useState(false)
  const contentRef = useRef(null)
  const [displayButton, setDisplayButton] = useState(false)
  const [contentMinimumHeight, setContentMinimumHeight] = useState(null)
  const windowSize = useWindowSize()

  const linesShown = windowSize.mobile
    ? parseInt(linesToShow[0])
    : parseInt(linesToShow[1])

  const handleToggleIsActive = () => {
    if (isActive && handleScroll) {
      handleScroll()
    }
    setIsActive(!isActive)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const contentLineHeight = parseInt(
      window
        .getComputedStyle(contentRef.current, null)
        .getPropertyValue('line-height')
    )

    const contentHeight = contentRef.current.scrollHeight

    // Adding 5 here to offset rounding that seems to occur in actual pixel values of rendered output, value of 5 is arbitrary.
    const linesToShowHeight = contentLineHeight * linesShown + 5
    setContentMinimumHeight(linesToShowHeight)

    console.log('Content height: ', contentHeight)
    console.log('Lines to show height: ', linesToShowHeight)

    if (contentHeight > linesToShowHeight) {
      setDisplayButton(true)
    }

    if (contentHeight < linesToShowHeight) {
      setDisplayButton(false)
    }
  }, [windowSize])

  return (
    <div sx={{ ...containerStyles }}>
      <div
        sx={{
          display: '-webkit-box',
          '-webkit-line-clamp': !isActive ? linesToShow : 'none',
          lineClamp: !isActive ? linesToShow : 'none',
          '-webkit-box-orient': 'vertical',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          outline: '2px solid red',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
          minHeight: contentMinimumHeight,
          '&:first-child': {
            marginTop: '0px',
          },
        }}
      >
        {markdown ? (
          <div
            ref={contentRef}
            sx={{
              ...textStyles,
              '& *:first-child': {
                marginTop: '0px',
                // marginBottom: '0px',
              },
            }}
            dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
              __html: text,
            }}
          />
        ) : (
          <p
            ref={contentRef}
            sx={{
              whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
              ...textStyles,
            }}
          >
            {text}{' '}
          </p>
        )}
      </div>
      {displayButton && (
        <Button
          variant="viewMore"
          sx={{ marginTop: '20px', ...buttonStyles }}
          onClick={handleToggleIsActive}
        >
          {!isActive ? 'Read more' : 'Read Less'}{' '}
          <ChevronDown
            styles={{ transform: !isActive ? 'none' : 'rotate(180deg)' }}
          />
        </Button>
      )}
    </div>
  )
}

export default CollapsibleText
```

To determine the content height, I'm using a ref and grabbing the scroll height of the element in question. I get the same value in Chrome and Firefox, but a larger value in Safari, which breaks my ability to selectively render the "toggle" button I'm trying to implement.

I'm comparing the "line height" (with my admittedly very simplistic algorithm) against the content height to determine whether or not to render the button. I get the same measurement in all three browsers, so as far as I can tell Safari is just measuring the scroll height of the content differently than in Chrome and Firefox.

I seemingly have to use a min height because the `line-clamp` property causes the content to collapse to zero in Safari. Setting the min height allows things to work more or less as predicted where the content is more than the user-defined `lines to show` prop given to the component.

Screenshots of the console logs for the SAME content in each browser:

Firefox:
[image: Screenshot of console logs in Firefox which show an indicated content height (derived directly from scroll height) of 70px, with several logs indicating the same thing.]

Chrome:
[image: Screenshot of console logs in Chrome which show an indicated content height (derived directly from scroll height) of 70px, with several logs indicating the same thing.]

Safari:
[image: Screenshot of console logs in Safari which show an indicated content height (derived directly from scroll height) of 87px, with several logs indicating the same thing.]